# Implement Anyfix Notation!

Tags: code-golf, string, interpreter

In prefix notation, the operator comes before the arguments, so you can kind of imagine that the operator calls `next()` which is recursively called. In infix notation, the operator goes between the arguments, so you can imagine it simply as a parse tree. In postfix notation, the operator comes after the arguments, so you can just imagine it as stack-based.

In anyfix notation, the operator can go anywhere<sup>*</sup>. If an operator shows up and there aren't enough arguments, then the operator waits until there are enough arguments. For this challenge, you are to implement a very basic anyfix evaluator. (Note that anyfix is a recreational language that I abandoned that you can play around with [here](https://tio.run/#anyfix) or check out [here](https://github.com/alexander-liao/anyfix))

You will need to support the following commands:

#### (Arity 1)

- duplicate
- negative

#### (Arity 2)

- addition
- multiplication
- equality: returns `0` or `1`.

You may choose to use any five non-whitespace symbols for these commands. For demonstrational purposes, I will use `"` as duplicate, `×` as multiplication, and `+` as addition.

For literals, you only need to support non-negative integers, but your interpreter must be able to contain all integers (within your language's (reasonable) integer range).

Let's take a look at an example: `10+5`. The storage should behave as a stack, not a queue. So first, the stack starts at `[]`, and the queued operator list starts at `[]`. Then, the literal `10` is evaluated which makes the stack `[10]`. Next, the operator `+` is evaluated, which requires two arguments. However, there is only one argument on the stack, so the queued operator list becomes `['+']`. Then, the literal `5` is evaluated which makes the stack `[10, 5]`. At this point, the operator `'+'` can be evaluated so it is, making the stack `[15]` and the queue `[]`.

The final result should be `[15]` for `+ 10 5`, `10 + 5`, and `10 5 +`.

Let's take a look at a harder example: `10+"`. The stack and queue start as `[]` and `[]`. `10` is evaluated first which makes the stack `[10]`. Next, `+` is evaluated, which doesn't change the stack (because there are not enough arguments) and makes the queue `['+']`. Then, `"` is evaluated. This can run immediately so it is, making the stack `[10, 10]`. `+` can now be evaluated so the stack becomes `[20]` and the queue `[]`. The final result is `[20]`.

What about order of operations?

Let's take a look at `×+"10 10`. The stack and queue start both as `[]`:

- `×`: The stack is unchanged and the queue becomes `['×']`.
- `+`: The stack is unchanged and the queue becomes `['×', '+']`.
- `"`: The stack is unchanged and the queue becomes `['×', '+', '"']`.
- `10`: The stack becomes `[10]`. Even though `×` should be the first operator to be evaluated since it appears first, `"` can run immediately and none of the operators before it can, so it is evaluated. The stack becomes `[10, 10]` and the queue `['×', '+']`. `×` can now be evaluated, which makes the stack `[100]` and the queue `['+']`.
- `10`: The stack becomes `[100, 10]`, which allows `+` to be evaluated. The stack becomes `[110]` and the queue `[]`.

The final result is `[110]`.

The commands used in these demonstrations are consistent with that of the anyfix language; however, the last example will not work due to a bug in my interpreter. (Disclaimer: Your submissions will not be used in the anyfix interpreter)

## Challenge

Select a set of 5 non-whitespace non-digit characters and create an anyfix interpreter according to the specifications above. Your program can either output the singular array or the value contained by it; it is guaranteed that the stack of values will only contain a single value at the end of execution and that the queue of operators will be empty at the end of execution.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

## Test Cases

For these test cases, duplicate is `"`, negative is `-`, addition is `+`, multiplication is `×`, and equality is `=`.

```
Input -> Output
1+2×3 -> 9
1"+"+ -> 4
2"××" -> 16
3"×+" -> 18
3"+×" -> 36
123"= -> 1 ("= always gives 1)
1+2=3 -> 1
1"=2+ -> 3
1-2-+ -> -3
-1-2+ -> 3 (hehe, the `-1` becomes `+1` at the `-` rather than making the `2` a `-1`)
+×"10 10 -> 200 (after the 10 is duplicated (duplication is delayed), 10 + 10 is performed and then 20 * 10, giving 200)
```

## Rules

- Standard Loopholes Apply
- You may take the anyfix official interpreter and golf it if you would like. Expect to lose horribly.

Input will be given as a string and output as an array, a single integer, out the string representation of either. You may assume that the input will only contain spaces, digits, and the 5 characters you choose.

<sup>* not actually</sup>

Comment: Go anywhere\*™.

Comment: What's the result of the equality operator? `0` and `1`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan lol

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yes, sorry, I forgot to specify that. It's `0/1`.

Comment: @geokavel whoops I removed subtraction

Comment: @JonathanAllan see above; I removed a command rip

Comment: What is the input format? Can I take a list of tokens? Can I take a string and require each number and operator be separated by a space? Ultimately, I'm trying to not special case multi-digit integer input.

Comment: @BrianJ Input is as a string. Tokenization is part of the challenge.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino May we assume that the input contains only digits, whitespace, and our 5 characters?

Comment: @BrianJ Input is as a string. Tokenization is part of the challenge.

Comment: @L3viathan Yes you may, thanks.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Sure.

Comment: You probably should include `×+"10 10` in the test cases, or any other examples that are 1) using a whitespace and 2) delaying the use of the _duplicate_ operator (two things that I missed entirely).

Comment: @Arnauld Yup, I'll include that, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>204</s> <s>203</s> 200 bytes

Returns an integer.

```js
e=>e.replace(/\d+|\S/g,v=>{for((1/v?s:v>','?u:b)[U='unshift'](v);!!u[0]/s[0]?s[U](u.pop()>'c'?s[0]:-S()):!!b[0]/s[1]?s[U](+eval(S(o=b.pop())+(o<'$'?'==':o)+S())):0;);},s=[],u=[],b=[],S=_=>s.shift())|s
```

Characters used:

- `+`: addition
- `*`: multiplication
- `#`: equality
- `d`: duplicate
- `-`: negative

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

e=>e.replace(/\d+|\S/g,v=>{for((1/v?s:v>','?u:b)[U='unshift'](v);!!u[0]/s[0]?s[U](u.pop()>'c'?s[0]:-S()):!!b[0]/s[1]?s[U](+eval(S(o=b.pop())+(o<'$'?'==':o)+S())):0;);},s=[],u=[],b=[],S=_=>s.shift())|s

;[ '10+5', '10+d', '*+d10 10', '1+2*3', '1d+d+', '2d**d', '3d*+d', '3d+*d', '123d#', '1+2#3', '1d#2+', '1-2-+', '-1-2+' ]
.forEach(e => console.log(e, '-->', f(e)))
```

#### Formatted and commented

```js
e => e.replace(                     // given an expression e, for each value v matching
  /\d+|\S/g, v => {                 // a group of digits or any other non-whitespace char.
    for(                            //   this loop processes as many operators as possible
      (                             //   insert v at the beginning of the relevant stack:
        1 / v ? s : v > ',' ? u : b //     either value, unary operator or binary operator
      )[U = 'unshift'](v);          //     (s[], u[] or b[] respectively)
      !!u[0] / s[0] ?               //   if there's at least 1 value and 1 unary operator:
        s[U](                       //     unshift into s[]:
          u.pop() > 'c' ?           //       for the duplicate operator:
            s[0]                    //         a copy of the last value
          :                         //       else, for the negative operator:
            -S()                    //         the opposite of the last value
        ) :                         //     end of unshift()
      !!b[0] / s[1] ?               //   if there's at least 2 values and 1 binary operator:
        s[U](                       //     unshift into s[]:
          +eval(                    //       the result of the following expression:
            S(o = b.pop()) +        //         the last value, followed by the
            (o < '$' ? '==' : o) +  //         binary operator o with '#' replaced by '=='
            S()                     //         followed by the penultimate value
          )                         //       end of eval()
        ) : 0;                      //     end of unshift()
    );                              //   end of for()
  },                                // end of replace() callback
  s = [],                           // initialize the value stack s[]
  u = [],                           // initialize the unary operator stack u[]
  b = [],                           // initialize the binary operator stack b[]
  S = _ => s.shift()                // S = helper function to shift from s[]
) | s                               // return the final result
```

Comment: Don't think this works for `-1+-2`.  Returns 3 instead of -3.

Comment: @RickHitchcock My understanding is that the 2nd `-` must be applied to `-1` immediately.

Comment: I would think the 2nd `-` would go with the `2` since it comes *after* another operator.  Perhaps @HyperNeutrino can clarify.  The negative operator may be ambiguous in some situations.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>162</s> <s>152</s> <s>143</s> 150 bytes

```
(s,N=s.replace(/(-?\d+)-|-(-)/g,'- $1 ').match(/(- ?)*?\d+|R/g))=>+eval(`R=${N[0]>'9'?N[1]:N[0]},${s.match(/[+*=]/g).map((o,i)=>'R=R'+o+'='+N[i+1])}`)
```

**Slightly ungolfed:**

```js
(s,
 N=s.replace(/(-?\d+)-|-(-)/g,'- $1 ').      //change postfix negatives to prefix,
                                             //and change "--" to "- - "
     match(/(- ?)*?\d+|R/g)                  //grab numbers and duplicates
)=>+eval(`R=${N[0] > '9' ?  N[1] : N[0]},    //handle a delayed duplicate
          ${s.match(/[+*=]/g).               //grab the operators
              map((o,i)=>'R=R'+o+'='+N[i+1]) //create a comma-separated list of assignments
           }
         `)
```

**Explanation**

I'm using `*` for multiplication and `R` for duplicate.  The other operators are the same as in the question.

`N` becomes the array of the numbers (including the duplicates).

The `replace` handles the case where the negative sign comes *after* the number.  For example, it will change `1-` to `- 1`  and `-1-` to `- -1` .

Within the `eval`, `s.match` creates the array of binary operators.  Note that this will always have one fewer elements than `N`.

The result of the function is the `eval` of the mapping of the numbers and operators.

Here is what is `eval`ed for each of the test cases:

```
0+2*3        R=0,R=R+=2,R=R*=3        = 6 
1+2*3        R=1,R=R+=2,R=R*=3        = 9 
1R+R+        R=1,R=R+=R,R=R+=R        = 4 
2R**R        R=2,R=R*=R,R=R*=R        = 16 
3R*+R        R=3,R=R*=R,R=R+=R        = 18 
3R+*R        R=3,R=R+=R,R=R*=R        = 36 
123R=        R=123,R=R==R             = 1 
1+2=3        R=1,R=R+=2,R=R==3        = 1 
1R=2+        R=1,R=R==R,R=R+=2        = 3 
1-2-+        R=- 1,R=R+=- 2           = -3 
-1-2+        R=1,R=R+=2               = 3 
*+R10 10     R=10,R=R*=10,R=R+=10     = 110 
+*R10 10     R=10,R=R+=10,R=R*=10     = 200 
-1+--2       R=-1,R=R+=- -2           = 1 
-1+-2        R=-1,R=R+=-2             = -3
```

The comma operator in a JavaScript expression returns the result of its last expression, so the `map` automatically returns a usable expression.

The `+` sign is needed before the `eval` to change `true` to `1` and `false` to `0`.

Using `R` as both the variable *and* the duplicate operator greatly simplifies the `map`'s sub-expressions.

**Test cases:**

```js
let f=

(s,N=s.replace(/(-?\d+)-|-(-)/g,'- $1 ').match(/(- ?)*?\d+|R/g))=>+eval(`R=${N[0]>'9'?N[1]:N[0]},${s.match(/[+*=]/g).map((o,i)=>'R=R'+o+'='+N[i+1])}`)

console.log(f('1+2*3'))    // 9
console.log(f('1R+R+'))    // 4
console.log(f('2R**R'))    // 16
console.log(f('3R*+R'))    // 18
console.log(f('3R+*R'))    // 36
console.log(f('123R='))    // 1
console.log(f('1+2=3'))    // 1
console.log(f('1R=2+'))    // 3
console.log(f('1-2-+'))    // -3
console.log(f('-1-2+'))    // 3
console.log(f('*+R10 10')) //110
console.log(f('+*R10 10')) //200
console.log(f('-1+--2'));  // 1
console.log(f('-1+-2'));  // -3
```

Comment: I don't think the `replace` works as intended. This returns `3` for `-1+--2` and I think `1` would be correct (the `1` changes sign three times before there's a second argument for the `+` available, resulting in `-1 + 2`).

Comment: Great catch, @FelixPalmen.  Now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>321</s> 311 bytes

```
_="f=a=>(a.replace(/\\d+|./g,mq!~(b='+*=\"- '.indexOf(a))|b>2j3j4j5&&o+aw1/y?(y*=-1wcz:1/y?oywcz:hz,rql.map(z=>m(lki,1)[0],i)),hq1/s[1]?sk0,2,+eval(`y${a=='='?a+a:a}s[1]`)):cz,cqlki,0,a),s=[],l=[],e='splice'),s)z(a,i)ys[0]w)^r``:q=z=>os.unshift(k[e](j?b-";for(i of"jkoqwyz")with(_.split(i))_=join(pop());eval(_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVHbjtowFHz3V1Cr2tjYceJQKpWV4RP6AYQSE5zFwcRJnG4uZfvrNEZV@3I056KZ0ZlSvkuXt7ruwsqe1eNxFLAQUmyRZK2qjcwVitL0TO4seqO35tNvdBIBWYoUhouA6eqshu8FkhjfT9ukXJVfyvXLiyWy59G4Q@NShLzPp43v7OjRZaJtY9hN1mgS2xsyV0053scHqjGml4ZHbs8PO3eNaUKJepcGZePnX1KIQAQ7SeRGfviLDONNPtG88QQxlZg6sT9Q44sSgauNzlUwT/GE5Mw9ulmjxz/aLNs0Ypa2jv2s3EUXHbru1QGVu1MIXwvbIr2wBSyvtunHCeJedxd0ZJ6wQ7PHoyitrlBta4Tx69PgET9yWzlrFDP2DWWAk2RYAQ4JJCCBwwDBCg7EVzJjHpM1mFseL3gMvopvIFyLcA34IoGEgOyvVpS2aXVP23taRZgV2nSqRXM0Ej@/59H/jIY5nmAZ4H@7ZyjMW83SKsOPPw)

The five characters are the same as in the question, except `*` is for multiplication.
The script is compressed using [RegPack](https://siorki.github.io/regPack.html). The original script is stored in the variable `_` after evaluation.

Comment: Don't think this works for `-1+-2`.  Returns 3 instead of -3.

Comment: @RickHitchcock. Why do you believe it should return `-3` instead of `3`?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the negative operator.  Generally, `-1 + -2` is `-3`, but should it be parsed as `--1 + 2` instead?

Comment: @RickHitchcock. I am pretty sure the result is `3`. Before `2` even come on the stack, the second `-` is evaluated, and therefore we have `1 2 +` which is indeed `3`. Ah, and probably you have to edit your answer too.

Comment: You're probably right.  You and Arnauld get the same answer, and I've asked the OP for clarification.  Would vote you up again if I could.

Answer (score 2):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), 697 bytes

```
00 C0 A2 00 86 29 86 26 86 27 86 28 86 4B 86 4C 86 CC 20 E4 FF F0 FB C9 0D F0
10 C9 20 30 F3 A6 27 9D B7 C2 20 D2 FF E6 27 D0 E7 C6 CC A9 20 20 1C EA A9 0D
20 D2 FF 20 95 C0 20 09 C1 20 95 C0 A6 26 E4 27 F0 4E BD B7 C2 E6 26 C9 20 F0
E8 C9 2D D0 09 A6 4C A9 01 9D B7 C3 D0 32 C9 22 D0 09 A6 4C A9 02 9D B7 C3 D0
25 C9 2B D0 09 A6 4C A9 81 9D B7 C3 D0 18 C9 2A D0 09 A6 4C A9 82 9D B7 C3 D0
0B C9 3D D0 0D A6 4C A9 83 9D B7 C3 E6 28 E6 4C D0 A3 4C 8A C2 A6 29 F0 6F A4
28 F0 6B CA F0 4B C6 28 A6 4B E6 4B BD B7 C3 F0 F5 30 14 AA CA D0 0B 20 7B C2
20 E1 C1 20 4D C2 D0 D9 20 5C C2 D0 D4 29 0F AA CA D0 0B 20 6D C2 20 08 C2 20
4D C2 D0 C3 CA D0 0B 20 6D C2 20 16 C2 20 4D C2 D0 B5 20 6D C2 20 F4 C1 20 4D
C2 D0 AA A4 4B B9 B7 C3 F0 02 10 AC C8 C4 4C F0 0F B9 B7 C3 F0 F6 30 F4 AA A9
00 99 B7 C3 F0 A6 60 A0 00 A6 26 E4 27 F0 15 BD B7 C2 C9 30 30 0E C9 3A 10 0A
E6 26 99 37 C4 C8 C0 05 D0 E5 C0 00 F0 08 A9 00 99 37 C4 20 39 C2 60 A2 FF E8
BD 37 C4 D0 FA A0 06 88 CA 30 0A BD 37 C4 29 0F 99 37 C4 10 F2 A9 00 99 37 C4
88 10 F8 A9 00 8D 3D C4 8D 3E C4 A2 10 A0 7B 18 B9 BD C3 90 02 09 10 4A 99 BD
C3 C8 10 F2 6E 3E C4 6E 3D C4 CA D0 01 60 A0 04 B9 38 C4 C9 08 30 05 E9 03 99
38 C4 88 10 F1 30 D2 A2 06 A9 00 9D 36 C4 CA D0 FA A2 10 A0 04 B9 38 C4 C9 05
30 05 69 02 99 38 C4 88 10 F1 A0 04 0E 3D C4 2E 3E C4 B9 38 C4 2A C9 10 29 0F
99 38 C4 88 10 F2 CA D0 D6 C0 05 F0 06 C8 B9 37 C4 F0 F6 09 30 9D 37 C4 E8 C8
C0 06 F0 05 B9 37 C4 90 F0 A9 00 9D 37 C4 60 A9 FF 45 FC 85 9F A9 FF 45 FB 85
9E E6 9E D0 02 E6 9F 60 A2 00 86 9F A5 FB C5 FD D0 07 A5 FC C5 FE D0 01 E8 86
9E 60 A5 FB 18 65 FD 85 9E A5 FC 65 FE 85 9F 60 A9 00 85 9E 85 9F A2 10 46 FC
66 FB 90 0D A5 FD 18 65 9E 85 9E A5 FE 65 9F 85 9F 06 FD 26 FE CA 10 E6 60 20
33 C1 A6 29 AD 3D C4 9D 3F C4 AD 3E C4 9D 3F C5 E6 29 60 A6 29 A5 9E 9D 3F C4
A5 9F 9D 3F C5 E6 29 60 A6 29 BD 3E C4 9D 3F C4 BD 3E C5 9D 3F C5 E6 29 60 C6
29 A6 29 BD 3F C4 85 FD BD 3F C5 85 FE C6 29 A6 29 BD 3F C4 85 FB BD 3F C5 85
FC 60 A6 29 BD 3E C5 10 13 20 7B C2 20 E1 C1 20 4D C2 A9 2D 20 D2 FF A6 29 BD
3E C5 8D 3E C4 BD 3E C4 8D 3D C4 20 8B C1 A9 37 A0 C4 4C 1E AB
```

**[Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"anyfix.prg":"data:;base64,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"%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"anyfix.prg"%7D%7D)**

**Usage** `sys49152`, then enter the anyfix expression and press return.

- close to no error checking, so expect funny outputs on invalid expressions.
- the symbol for multiplication is `*`, all others as suggested.
- maximum input length is 256 characters, there can be no more than 127 operators queued.
- The input routine **doesn't** handle control characters, so don't mistype ;)
- integers are 16bit signed, overflow will silently wrap around.
- byte count is a bit large because this CPU doesn't even know multiplication and the C64 OS / ROM doesn't give you **any** integer arithmetics or conversions to/from decimal strings.

Here's the [readable ca65-style assembler source code](https://github.com/Zirias/c64anyfix/tree/a071e10c977321b5bd5a8771536836a0c90d90ee).

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 251 bytes

```hs
(#([],[]))
(x:r)#(o,n)|x>'9'=r#h(o++[x],n)|[(a,t)]<-lex$x:r=t#h(o,read a:n)
_#(o,n:_)=n
h=e.e
e(o:s,n:m:r)|o>'N'=e(s,g[o]n m:r)
e(o:s,n:r)|o=='D'=e(s,n:n:r)|o=='N'=e(s,-n:r)
e(o:s,n)|(p,m)<-e(s,n)=(o:p,m)
e t=t
g"a"=(+)
g"m"=(*)
g"q"=(((0^).abs).).(-)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5JbsMgFN1zCkQqGYqxClRRY4WsvK0v4LoRTZ1BNXhcWGp6jhwo96oLdhR19cb/4Ki7r6Isx716G/ECZ3mY5YQAPMQtWeAqtOQ8bIJVoNrFEVeUZkPuvQzrsCf5mpXF8OC6qvdx2Bb6E@rYErCdjuMtURYcVREVoMBV3DnLuOVztQnSQBW4Cw9ZlVvozXvD50oFyVyw8d25nTD7r03OuA4NWbOpS5RzvQYF7FUPDkgjhSlxxDjy6EnjCMZP7yTSHx2JSIQZGY0@Waig0fUrxHV7sj2M4J7ADHEtjEQh4olOtEORGJM4lInRM@pJcyGTxqMWzdxvhO/zVKQeU0c8uisJ@RPKwTcDnIrrRUK2gSvAEUXU02cg0PVyvSAv@BJIp@gsXpygt0QugXsTqSnwS0reKFJiGpKAM8EmyiRgTtxsv@c/MfVXgP2Mv7t9qQ/dyHZ1/Qc) Uses the following characters: `a` for addition, `m` for multiplication, `q` for equality, `D` for duplicate and `N` for negation. (I wanted to use `e` for equality, but ran into the problem that `lex` parses `2e3` as a number.) Example usage: `(#([],[])) "2a3 4m"` yields `20`.

Answer (score 1):

## VB.NET (.NET 4.5) <s>615</s> 576 bytes

*-39 bytes thanks to Felix Palmen by changing `\r\n` to `\n`*

Requires `Imports System.Collections.Generic` (included in byte count)

```
Dim s=New Stack(Of Long),q=New List(Of String),i=Nothing,t=0,c=0
Function A(n)
For Each c In n
If Long.TryParse(c,t)Then
i=i &"0"+t
Else
If c<>" "Then q.Add(c)
If i<>A Then s.Push(i)
i=A
End If
If i=A Then E
Next
If i<>A Then s.Push(i)
E
A=s
End Function
Sub E()
c=s.Count
If c=0Then Exit Sub
For Each op In q
If op="-"Or op="d"Or c>1Then
Select Case op
Case"*"
s.Push(s.Pop*s.Pop)
Case"+"
s.Push(s.Pop+s.Pop)
Case"="
s.Push(-(s.Pop=s.Pop))
Case"-"
s.Push(-s.Pop)
Case"d"
s.Push(s.Peek)
End Select
q.Remove(op)
E
Exit Sub
End If
Next
End Sub
```

The entry point is Function `A`, which takes a string as input and returns a `Stack(Of Long)`.

Symbols:

- Addition - `+`
- Multiplication - `*`
- Equality - `=`
- Negation - `-`
- Duplication - `d`

Overview:

Function `A` takes the input and tokenizes it. It uses a `Long?` to do a running total for multi-digit integers, which `Nothing` signifying we are not currently reading an integer.

Subroutine `E` takes the stack of integers and queue of operators, and evaluates the anyfix notation. It calls itself recursively until there are no actions left.

I declare global params all at once to save bytes on both declaration and parameter passing.

The return value from `A` is set by assigning a value to the matching variable `A`.

VB `True` is equivalent to `-1`, so that operation has to negate the result to get the correct value.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZRNj5swEIbv/hUjDi2EgIBUVSutV4q2bBVpv9Ss1GscPFmsBZxgs9v8@tQ2bEIPFTmEYd5nXnsmjt@2USFbPK3qvWy1gvVRaazjG1lVWGghGxX/xAZbUZB7ybsK4T49/RA1KPqA77DWrHj1H3dwJ5uXYH5wyTuhtM2tdStsVtAHqUsTzjVN5gVNyG3XOHNY@k1AbmULOStKKGDVQENWvV383B6fWKvQL@Y6eC6xIYIK@OQlXqhJXim0ZHF17YFnVTjES879IrBpcXW9BJdV8VOnSl8EpnpJ8obDaucIOgA5ecA/@n9FOVlS5co@Nk3W3RZyPyAFVWZQXeNqTVu92x@hwRCXruTetnWwkNxTL/IeWxdwGxTXqetsjXbecMMUGpHYpzfzyLAP85D7mfsOei38VwvHGj1rUa/SXh3k6CKPq/jYEfE1cE33@yKH@BfW8g19i@fk3OQwTjdAh3fbkx3PPRMNITB8bswxkhXGv1uh8U406C99Lw2z2cIL7A6AwvdgguYhD8/0lwk647MZP9Pp1wl8wWfhCP82iYcj98WUe5otOL24B/AZfE6BVe/sqOBFvKEy2clh0cXIY2pYNLsMazFFR1l0oaMpPDL82Ny2U2KJc9AlwiZKN7DFQtamq01oXpgehA20zESteWUN1OzV3Ai9lBnKVU4sbcaeJpAm59WzJHHrs512vmhEEAp4t69EwTRyM@ohtteNlbBiR@TB3KLhwO@x3cm2Njgzh1jb/3GWwMyoc/sD2Y3apQj5OOR90N@Ip78)

Comment: suggest to add [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJNT8MwDL3nV1g5oHYf1YDrMqkaBU3aBqKTOHepYRFt0iXpGL9@JGkZA4kcEuu9Z8fP8mE75krjaVE3SlsD@aexWCdzVVXIrVDSJA8oUQtOyEqVbYWQHYu6qfB0J2owbI0fkNuCv0ePr7BU8i0e7QO4FMZ6LLdaeFSwtbI7F44sm4w4m5D7VoYvII1kTO6VhqzgO@CwkCDJoiuXbPTnU6ENRnxk480OJRFMwBWd0KElWWXQK/l0RoF6FvZJWpYRjz0sprMUAmqSp9bsIhG77JRksoTFa1CwXpCRNR7tf0kZSZkJad9Nk7zdQhbFhDPjxtXKkOtsddWOwoJT/LhSjbe19yLVMDqmjzoEpQ/47Do4y9FPHeaFQUcS/9IBJX0f7lHNINxxxw1/c8NLjp25cceyju3p8Q99mVVeVkR8j4Ppri@yT56xVgeMvDwjZ5P9OMMAg7zdnsDfsCqEdDMCd/y6aEjNn20JnAbmloBeD28Gt7SD5m71VIXJixYWl0Ji1LcJ0H8Rvup28vQF)

Comment: btw, with the `Imports`, I get a byte count of only `576` -- could you have miscounted?

Comment: @FelixPalmen I counted with `\r\n` instead of `\n`, so that's where the discrepancy is.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Added TIO, thanks for reminding me! :) (Oh, I didn't realize you made it for this post already)